# Typescript. Проверка каждого существующего ключа объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

Когда меняется state таким образом, используя константы и аргументы

```
setChosenCategoryAudios({
  [buttonName]: !objCategoryAudios[buttonName],
});
```

typescript просит уточнение типа и ключа объекта тоже
И код приходится писать так

```
const initialStateActiveBtn: { [key: string]: boolean } = {
  myAudios: true,
  allAudios: false,
  friendsAudios: false,
};
```

Вместо такого

```
interface IinitialStateActiveBtn {
  myAudios: boolean;
  allAudios: boolean;
  friendsAudios: boolean;
}
const initialStateActiveBtn: IinitialStateActiveBtn  = {
  myAudios: true,
  allAudios: false,
  friendsAudios: false,
};
```

, но в первом случае typescript не следит за конкретным ключом, то есть если поставить левый ключ в коде с булевым значением он ругаться не будет. Кто знает если мы делаем таким образом изменение объекта, как задать проверку по каждому существующему ключу.

```
setChosenCategoryAudios({
  [buttonName]: !objCategoryAudios[buttonName],
});
```

Comment: Будет проще объяснить, если вы добавите объявление `setChosenCategoryAudios` в тело вопроса.

Comment: setChosenCategoryAudios({
  allAudios: !false,
});

Comment: Вы показываете вызов функции. Покажите как она объявляется.

Comment: Эту хук на реакте, вы точно разбираетесь?
const [objCategoryAudios, setChosenCategoryAudios] = useState(initialStateActiveBtn);